# How to set header/cookies for Titanium Network Socket TCP?

Tags: cookies, tcp, titanium, session-cookies, titanium-mobile

I'm trying download a image file from remote server using Titanium.Network.Socket.TCP.
Server requires header/cookies, how to set cookies?

Answer (score 0):

In HTTP requests, you can use the method **setRequestHeader** to include your header information.

For example:

```
xhr.setRequestHeader("X-Auth-Token", "foobar");
```

Docs: http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient-method-setRequestHeader